# Regular expression to prevent SQL injection

Tags: sql-injection

I know I have to escape single quotes, but I was just wondering if there's any other character, or text string I should guard against

I'm working with mysql and h2 database...

Answer (score 2):

This will somewhat depend on what type of information you need to obtain from the user.  If you are only looking for simple text, then you might as well ignore all special characters that a user might input (if it's not too much trouble)--why allow the user to input characters that don't make sense in your query?

Some languages have functions that will take care of this for you.  For example, PHP has the mysql_real_escape_string() function (http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-real-escape-string.php).

You are correct that single quotes (') are user input no-no's; but double quotes (") and backslashes (\) should also definitely be ignored (see the above link for which characters the PHP function ignores, since those are the most important and basic ones).

Hope this is at least a good start!

Answer (score 2):

If you check the MySQL function [mysql-real-escape-string](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/mysql-real-escape-string.html) which is used by all upper level languages you'll see that the strange characters list is quite huge:

- \
- '
- "
- NUL (ASCII 0)
- \n
- \r
- Control+Z

The upper language wrappers like the PHP one may also protect the strings from **malformed unicode characters** which may end up as a quote.

The conclusion is: **do not escape strings**, especially with hard-to-debug hard-to-read, hard-to-understand regular expressions. Use the **built-in provided functions** or use **parameterized SQL queries** (where all parameters cannot contain anything interpredted as SQL by the engine). This is also stated in h2 documentation: [h2 db sql injection protection](http://www.h2database.com/html/advanced.html#sql_injection).

> A simple solution for the problem above is to use a prepared statement: